# Why does the sentence have the indefinite article?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

> The WA premier Colin Barnett will appeal to Tony Abbott to help save
>   his state from **a** proposed 549-million dollar funding cut. [(ABC
>   News)](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2013-03-16/abc-news/4577144)

Why does the sentence select not 'the' but 'a'? : I guess the WA's appeal must have connected a specific proposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*proposed 549-million dollar funding cut* is a general description of the item, but a specific means (legislative bill, directive or such) is not specified. Generally speaking, there could be several proposals.
Therefore using *a* is appropriate.

If it was specified, you could say something like

> The WA premier Colin Barnett will appeal to Tony Abbott to help save his state from **the** proposed 549-million dollar funding cut, **Spending Bill A001**.

Answer (score 5):

It hadn't been introduced before.  If it said *the* proposed 549-million dollar funding cut, it would be referring to a proposed 549-million dollar funding cut that had previously been introduced to the reader.